# PHP Powerpoint Reader

Tags: php, powerpoint

PHPPowerpoint, great for making ppt, but still has no reader.

Any chance a reader will be written soon? Mark Baker?

This would be awesome to have since Google docs will download presentations in .ppt

Answer (score 0):

See this:

http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/27/PHPPowerPoint-010-%28CTP1%29-released!.aspx

Comment: I already know that, that's what I put in my post, PHPPowerpoint. It's fine as a writer, except it does not have a reader. [Link MarkBaker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) had mentioned possibly starting a reader this year (2011).